# the Expectation is equal the probability of the first exit time of openset

Tags: integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

let $X_{t}$ itô diffusion and $1_{A}(x):=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \in A, \\
0 &  otherwise. \end{cases}$
and   $\tau$ be The first exit time  defined by :
$$ \tau=\inf\{t>0:x_{t} \notin \Omega \}  \text{ with } \Omega \text{ be Open set of  }\mathbb{R}^{n} $$ 
$\mathbb{E}^{x}[1_{A}(X_{t})]= $
how we can say that expectation is equal the probability of the first exit time of $\Omega$ by $A$.

Indeed what i can say is :
$\mathbb{E}^{x}[1_{A}(X_{t})]=??\mathbb{P}^{x}[A(X_{t})] $
but this is probability of 
Please respond. I'll be grateful for any help offered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectation $\mathbb{E}^{x}[1_{A}(X_{\tau})]$ is the probability that the first exit of $\Omega$ occurs by a point in $A$.

More generally, for any event $B$, the expectation $\mathbb{E}^{x}[1_B]$ is the probability that $B$ occurs. In the case at hand, $B=[X_\tau\in A]$.

Comment: Thanks so much now it's clear now